# Postfix: Require login before sending email

Tags: 12.04, postfix

How can I configure my postfix to require the user to log in before sending email ? At the moment I can send emails without any login authentication...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it , you have to follow three steps

1. Provide a file, which will holds necessary information about credentials
2. Configure Postfix to enable SMTP AUTH for the smtp daemon
3. Configure Postfix to use the file with the SASL credentials

The login credentials are located in this file

```
/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

for example :`less /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`

```
[root@mail postfix]# cat /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
mail.my-isp.org      test:testpass
```

Here

Hostname: mail.my-isp.org

username :test

password:testpass

Process some what huge one , for Information please visit : [postfix.state-of-mind.de](http://postfix.state-of-mind.de/patrick.koetter/smtpauth/smtp_auth_mailservers.html)